# how to check whether username and password exists inside database(mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

i want to store username and password inside mongodb database and later on retrieve database values and check whether the username and password exists inside database.If it does exist then i would redirect to another page.How can i achieve this using node.js and mongodb.I am able to store the values inside database.But getting confused for how to fetch the values and check them against the values provide in form field values.There is no method in mongodb like fetchByName or something similar.
Can someone help me out with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should take a look on the [Nodepad](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/models.js#L58-84) source code, it explains very well how to achieve this with Mongoose:

```
  User.virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
      this._password = password;
      this.salt = this.makeSalt();
      this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() { return this._password; });

  User.method('authenticate', function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  });

  User.method('makeSalt', function() {
    return Math.round((new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())) + '';
  });

  User.method('encryptPassword', function(password) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
  });

  User.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password)) {
      next(new Error('Invalid password'));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try using an already existing library like [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) or [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth). There are other ones too, google them :)